# Where can I find the value of version variable?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I downloaded a multi-module-project, and I couldn't find the value of maven pom's.xml:

This is the parent's pom:

```html
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>cat.base.baseframe</groupId>
    <artifactId>projecte-pare-baseframe</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.11.a</version>
</parent>

<groupId>cat.base.adreces</groupId>
<artifactId>sca</artifactId>
<version>0.0.4.a</version>
<name>sca</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<description>Esquelet d'una aplicació BaseFrame</description>

<modules>
    <module>domini</module>
    <module>logica</module>
    <module>ejb</module>
    <module>assistent</module>
    <module>ear</module>
    <module>utils</module>
</modules>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludePackageNames>cat.base.adreces.assistent;cat.base.adreces.serveis.ejb;cat.base.adreces.domini.dao;cat.base.adreces.serveis.impl</excludePackageNames>
                <stylesheetfile>src/site/resources/stylesheet.css</stylesheetfile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

And this is a module pom.xml:

```html
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>cat.base.adreces</groupId>
    <artifactId>sca</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.4.a</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>sca.assistent</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>sca.assistent</name>
<description>Assistent d'adreces</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${project.parent.artifactId}.domini</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2_10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2_10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version> --->¿?
        <scope>provided</scope>
```

Where can I find the value of `${spring.version}`? Is it a special maven configuration or something like that?

Comment: It's probably declared in `cat.base.baseframe:projecte-pare-baseframe` or one of its parent POMs.

Comment: i can't make the world better....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a property is not defined in the POM then it might be defined in a parent POM.

To see the full configuration run:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

Comment: ty i can see all configuration with this sentence!

Answer (score 0):

It is *not* a maven special configuration, but rather a maven property.  Maven properties can have any name:

```
<properties>
    <spring-version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring-version>
    <cheeseburger-type>BIG</cheeseburger-type>
</properties>
```

In this case, the value could be defined either in a further ancestor pom (parent of the parent you posted, etc) or in ${USER_HOME}/.m2/settings.xml or ${MAVEN_HOME}/conf/settings.xml